# Binary combinations in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to refactor some code in my stored procedure which running on SQL server:

```
exec ATTRIBUTE_INSTALL 'Account ID', 0x0204
exec ATTRIBUTE_INSTALL 'Order Reference', 0x0201
exec ATTRIBUTE_INSTALL 'Cash Instruction Type', 0x8000
```

The second parameter of the procedure `ATTRIBUTE_INSTALL` means attribute options, which combined by various bits.

In C/C++ I usually write code like this:

```
attribute_install("Account ID", OPTION_READONLY | OPTION_LOCAL_ACCESSABLE)
attribute_install("Order Reference", OPTION_READONLY | OPTION_INTERNAL)
attribute_install("Cash Instruction Type", OPTION_DROP_DOWN_LIST)
```

Is there a similar way that makes SQL code easier to understand and maintain?

Comment: Normally in SQL, you would have separate columns for the attributes, or perhaps separate rows.  SQL isn't really into bit fiddling.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I wrote a long answer on how to do this in the linked question -- check it out.

Comment: @Hogan . . . I think it is a better idea to store a bunch of bit flags, rather than doing bit fiddling in SQL Server.  If you are going to use bit flags, then add computed columns so each bit can be accessed symbolically.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I can't argue with better -- but your comment implied not possible.  It is possible, but not advised.

Comment: @Hogan . . . I didn't mean to imply that it wasn't possible -- many databases support bitwise operations.  My intention is really to say that optimization in SQL is not about bit fiddling.